# How does a photodetector work more specifically?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fiber-optics

I’m studying how fiber-optic communication works. To transmit a signal, you need a transmitter that converts electrical impulses into luminous and a photodetector that performs the reverse operation. The operation of the transmitter is clear enough to me. Instead the photodetector seems a bit more complex.Could someone explain the physical/electrical functioning of a photodetector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commonly, they use the photoelectric effect in a semiconductor. An incoming photon ionizes an atom, producing both a free electron and a free "hole". Separate them with an electric field, collect them, and you get a current. Often, these detectors are operated in "avalanche" mode, where the field is strong enough to give the electron enough energy to ionize another atom, producing a free electron that ionizes another atom, continuing until all the electrons have been collected. This gives you more charge per photon, improving the sensitivity of the detector system.